# Determine the sequence of execution of statements in an Android app?

Tags: java, android, debugging, reverse-engineering

I have to reverse engineer an Android app in order to learn how its code works. I have used jadx v1.1.0 to to view the apps components(source code etc.), but this application only allows me to view the source code. I don't know how can I debug the code, or figure out the order of execution of the code. I don't know what's the head and what's the tail of this Android app.

What can I do to tackle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Well you'll certainly have to do a little research before trying to read an android app. How much research is required though, depends on your familiarity with the Java language. If you are already familiar with the syntax, then you can skip right to the Android components lifecycles (this is assuming your goal is simply to understand what is going on in the app, not learn how to write Android applications).

I would start with this set of Medium articles. The author does a great job simply explaining the various lifecycles of Android components and their callback methods:

- https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/the-android-lifecycle-cheat-sheet-part-i-single-activities-e49fd3d202ab
- https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/the-android-lifecycle-cheat-sheet-part-ii-multiple-activities-a411fd139f24
- https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/the-android-lifecycle-cheat-sheet-part-iii-fragments-afc87d4f37fd

If you can take in the lifecycles of Android components and their related callback methods, you should be able to get a general idea of what is going on. Look for the Java files with the words "Activity" or "Fragment" in their names, I would start there. Within those files, look for the callback methods following the naming convention of `onCreate`, `onResume`, `onDestroy`, etc. If you read the above mentioned articles, you'd have a general idea of the order in which they are called and you can figure out the app's order of execution.

From there, there are many ways to branch off. I have a feeling that this will give you a decent enough start with enough knowledge to know what to research from there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn a bit more about the Android platform in order to have a basis for documenting the basic sequence of events, but depending on the complexity of the application, this may become a considerable effort.

I would suggest reviewing the *manifest* file, which will help you determine which (if applicable) activities are the launcher, as well as defining any permissions, services, and receivers. Also look for a class that extends *Application*. This will be your first point of execution on launch. Please also review the Android documentation, and samples to get an idea of typical application structure.

It is possible to migrate this source code into a stubbed Android project in order to debug it, but it will take time and patience.